# Linux storage database access methods - Hash and recno

Tags: linux, filesystems, database

There are plenty of other better file system organization methods but why does linux use these in specific ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its entirely dependent on what filesystem you're using.  If you're using ext4 then it's because they made it backwards compatible all the way back to ext2.  If you want a better system don't blame Linux, just switch to btrfs.